# Keyword "this" Inside If statement In Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `onkeypress` event and I want to manipulate element `this`. I also have `if` statement in the event function. The problem is that the keyword `this` is different inside the `if` statement block. Is it normal to be like this. What explanation do you have?

example:

```
$(o).find('input[name=numeric]').keypress(
    function (e) {
        var a = this; // the real object element which activate the trigger
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var b = this; //here "this" is different object 
        }
        else
            window.ncb.helper.validator.numeric(e);
    }
);
```

Comment: console.log(a === b)

Comment: _"here "this" is different object"_... __NO...__

Comment: I'm sure that isn't true. Inside of your `if` block, try doing `console.log(a === b)`. I guarantee you it'll be `true`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Right. It's proving that they're the *exact* same object.

Comment: @procrastinator Check it out bud: [Object comparison in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript) and [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: @PraveenKumar, Both the variables are pointing to the same reference.. That is the reason of _"true"_

Comment: @PraveenKumar I'm not trying to perform property-based equality. I'm saying that `a` and `b` refer to the exact same *instance* of an object. The [`this` scope does not change when entering an `if` block.](https://jsfiddle.net/0yt9bxse/) Please stop cluttering the comments with your misunderstanding.

Comment: @MikeC, There is point in being _rude_.. Praveens comment(_"That's not how you compare objects"_) is not totally invalid.. Just ain't applicable in current context...

Comment: @Rayon His comments are a bit rude, [not constructive and chatty.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244203/what-does-not-constructive-mean-and-how-does-it-differ-from-too-chatty?lq=1) That's enough reason to request that he stop cluttering up the comments section.

Comment: @procrastinator I am not sure if the reference - will be the same? Not sure then.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. At the start of the if statement all is fine and visible. After that I replace html content which `this` lives inside of the `old` replaced content. Thank you anyway.